# Find clickable elements

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to find all clickable elements specified with either click() or live('click) ?

I want to perform some actions if any of such elements are clicked.

```
$('.container').bind('click', function(event) {
    // actions
});
```

This one catches all clicks.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/661806/405398

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$.each($('.container').find("*").andSelf().data("events"), function(i, event) {
    $.each(event, function(j, h) {
        if(j = 'click')
        {
            //Do stuff to $(this)
            alert(j);
            alert(h.handler); //Gets the actual handler for each event ( inject code >=] )
        }
    });
});
```

### Working JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vFaAK/

Comment: If the containers themselves are clickable then you may wish to consider `$.each($(".container").find('*').andSelf().data("events"), ....`