# How to keep query string parameters as user navigates through the website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a situation where I want to preserve a query string between clicks on my Wordpress website.

E.g.
www.mywebsite.com/?utm_source=mysource

When navigating from this link to another page of the website that query string should persist.

E.g. 
www.mywebsite.com/anotherpage/?utm_source=mysource

So I decided one easy way to do this would be to modify the javascript so that my function is fired when a click on an anchor tag occurs.

```
//Ensures that the query string persists between clicks on the site
  $("a").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();   
    window.location.href = event.currentTarget.href + window.location.search;  
  });
```

However this doesn't work for other elements on the page like buttons which are not anchor tags but still contain hrefs that modifiy the window location when they are clicked. For example in the php scripts of the theme there is code such as:

```
<button onClick="location.href=www.anotherwebsite.com"</button>
```

I could implement another function that implements the same behavior for button elements but I am concerned that whenever another element is added I will have to check for a new type. Is there a better way to ensure that whenever the window location is changed my query string persists?

FYI: I am not allowed to put the information in a cookie which is another way I thought of keeping track of the parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query string of referrer URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884803/query-string-of-referrer-url)

Comment: The above doesn't solve my problem very eloquently as I would have to add the $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; to every script where the user is directed to a new link, if I had many pages in my website that could involve modifying a lot of code and writing a lot of duplicate code

Comment: that's only one of 3 answers though.

Comment: why not use sessions?

Comment: I found some older questions that suggest trying to intercept the location change using a beforeunload handler, but I am not too sure how reliably that would work. And there isn’t much else you could use to intercept just any arbitrary navigation event - history changes fire only when navigation happens via the browser history UI, but not for normal link or button clicks. // Seems a bit counter-intuitive that you want to not only track my initial visit to your page, but to keep sniffing after my a** as I navigate further through the site … but then have that requirement to not use cookies …?

Answer (score 2):

several suggestions
client side
In using jquery, it might be easier to just [find clickable elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238119/find-clickable-elements), or have the WordPress theme add css classes, if useful ones aren't there already.

server side
In WordPress, use sessions (but see below), and a rewrite or redirect rule using `add_query_arg()`.
Note about sessions and WordPress: You can't rely on PHP sessions; instead use the database, perhaps via an existing plugin like WP Session Manager or WordPress Native PHP Sessions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to append query paramters in all anchor tags:-**

```
    $('a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var querystring = 
    window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1);
        if(href && querystring){
           if(querystring.indexOf('=') >= 0) 
              {
                  $(this).attr('href', href+'?'+querystring);
              }
        }
   });
```