# Find Elements With Events Attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am looking for a way to find all elements inside a container that have an event handler attached to them via a selector. This needs to include delegated/live events.

In the following example the selector should find all 3 buttons including the 'Action' ones which have delgated events.

```
<div id='container'>
    <button id='test_btn'>Test</button>
    <button id='live_btn_id1'>Action</button>
    <button id='live_btn_id2'>Action</button>
</div>
```

```js
$("#test_btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#container").find("*").off();
});

$("#container").on('click', 'button[id^=live_btn]', function(event) { 
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain why are you selecting those elements? What are you planning to do with them? there can be some other alternatives also..

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661564/jquery-selector-that-search-for-events

Comment: You could always add a class.. http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/XNHNU/

Comment: I wish to then once I have them process them as to whether I will remove the events or keep them based on values stored in a data property.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you tried to say. If you remove event, you can extend that with `.removeClass('clickEvent')`.

Comment: Its quite simple I want to find all elements have an event handler attached ie .click so forth.

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea why my example was not what you wanted, because that is exactly what it does. You add click event, you add click class. You remove click event, you remove click class.

Comment: I want to do it a proper way with a selector rather then some hack by adding a class to it.

Comment: Class is a selector. Why that would be a hacky method is beyond me.

Comment: I don't want to add a class to it in order to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all events linked with your selector

```
$.each($('#container button').data('events'), function(i, event){
    $.each(event, function(i, handler){
        //Do what you want : condition on 'click' event for example
        console.log( handler.toString() );
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working for me I get the following error: "TypeError: a is undefined"

Comment: Also could be wrong but I am fairly certain they moved the events from the "data" object in one of the recent JQuery updates to some internal place.